# Is there a combination program that will generate a dictionary from a predefined list of words and numbers in specific order?

Tags: encryption, password-cracking, zip

I'm sorry if this question has been asked, but I've already wasted 6 precious hours trying to find a program that will accomplish the task I'm requesting. (Perhaps I'm asking the wrong question?)

Specifically, I want to create a dictionary of predefined words and numbers (numbers being in a specific order) for use with a cracker.  For example, I want to use the words "cat" and "fcw", as well as the numbers with predefined order "515" and "23".

I need to either populate a dictionary (probably faster) with all of the possible combinations with the length between 6 to 20 characters, or run a program with these predefined combinations.

It's been a long time since I've coded, so writing has been troublesome.

Any help or walk-through would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using which OS? In Unix world, what you describe seems just to be the daily duties for shell scripts. It would help though if you could give a short example of the expected result (I understood you have one file with words, another with number, and you would like to merge them into a new file containing "cat515", "cat23", "fcw515", "fcw23", is this correct?)

Comment: If your on Linux, look at `crunch`. [link1](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-like-pro-crack-passwords-part-4-creating-custom-wordlist-with-crunch-0156817/) [link2](http://adaywithtape.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/creating-wordlists-with-crunch-v30.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish is called password mutations, or definition rule-sets. I would use John the Ripper for this (JTR), not because i hate crunch, but just because i've been using it a long time and i can give you specific examples for it.

let say you have a word list, containing the various different base strings you wish to test.

```
cat
fcw
cfd
etc...
```

and you wish to try different combinations of them, maybe some added anomalies for completeness sake. well we can do that with a configuration file. (john defines this as rules, but its all the same)

basic password cracking looks ike this:

```
john mypasswordsdump --wordlist=stringlist.txt
```

this will test each password in stringlist against the hashes in the dump. simple. now we add the extra element.

in `/etc/john.conf` (im not sure where it is in the windows version but im sure its not hard to find) you may or may not see something like this:

```
[List.Rules:<somenamehere>]
```

these are the declaration of rule sets. and you can add some pretty nifty functons here. a wide variety in fact.  is important because this is how you tell john in the command line what rules to use against your passwords.

so for the sake of example we will use `[List.Rules:testrules]`

now there are some great resources for building these rules:

- http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/RULES.shtml
- http://juggernaut.wikidot.com/jtr#toc15

just as examples. but lets try something easy.

```
[List.Rules:testrules]
cAz"515"
```

running this is john like this:

```
john mypassworddump --wordlist=stringlist.txt --rules=testrules
```

will result in the first letter being capitalized, the rest of the word printing noramlly, and then appending 515 to the end and then trying each of those passwords against your hashes:

```
Cat515
Fcw515
Cfd515
etc...
```

of course the more complex you make the rules, the more diverse the passwords get and the more tries JTR will have to do.

instead of straight "515" we write [0-9], this will append a single digit to the end of each word, from 0 to 9 and moving on to the next one.

in this way many sorts of mutation can be defined. its a lot of fun!